# TA-Lib for python 3.11 version on Windows x64?

Tags: python, python-wheel, ta-lib

does anyone has a correct wheel for TA-Lib and python 3.11 running on Windows x64? The last one i have found is for 3.10 version.

There is an unofficial manual to do something similar to what i want, but i cannot understand what should i do next after 6th step when i run 'nmake' command. Maybe i need to compile the contents of the folder to WHL file?

> 1. Download and Unzip 'ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip' from https://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html
> 2. Move the Unzipped Folder ta-lib to C:\
> 3. Download and Install Visual Studio Community (2015 or later)
> 4. From Windows Start Menu, Start [VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt]
> 5. Move to C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc
> 6. Build the Library 'nmake'